# Can't open local terminal

Tags: android, terminal

I try to initialize my  terminal in Android Studio but it gives me error. It says

> Can't open local terminal. java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY

My computer runs on windows 10. How to fix this?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/bug-android-studio-terminal-wont-start-t3128098

Comment: In case anyone gets `Cannot open Local Terminal` error when running Android Studio Beta on **macOS**, it's a bug that has been found a few times and reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=%2Fbin%2Fzsh

Answer (score 3):

This problem was occured when, you clone one android project from Github Repository..

To solve this Problem, Open Settings, Go To Tools -> Terminal

Then, In the Project Settings, change the path of Start Directory to Your SDK's path like, For My System,
G:\MySoftware\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 2):

> This worked for me
>
> Please go the Settings -> Tools -> Terminal
> Then Change the shell path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could run studio.exe as administrator, if the solution not work, try another solution: add a Shell path(git-bash or others) to Android Studio Settings(setting--->Tools--->Terminal--->Shell path)